# Diagnostic for VAR model. non normal

Tags: time-series, modeling, econometrics, vector-autoregression, white-noise

I have some problem about my model.
my model is based on VAR. (vector auto-.)
well, I've tested ARCH test, BG test(autocorrelation p) and jarque.bera.test.
Model is stable. Also I got good result for ARCH and BG (both fail to reject) but I failed jarque.bera.test. What does it mean? 
I know it didn't satisfies white noise assumption but I was wondering if this suggest other model to use. Or is this because of omitted variable problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a very large sample, the jarque.bera test will almost always reject normality of the residuals for a VAR. I suggests you plot your residuals in a histogram and a qqplot to see for yourself if it is reasonable to believe that the residuals are behaving like white noise.

Comment: I have more than 1000 samples. Is this indicating that my sample is bad?

Comment: So 1000 data points for each variable? How does your qqplot and histogram look?